# Running TFS C# API in 64-bit application pool only

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using TFS 2010 and visual studio 2012.
I have created a C# api to connect to tfs. The code works. I used couple of microsoft.foundation dlls. They are using version 2.0
But I had to configure my application pool in IIS on my server (windows server 2008 64-bit) by setting Enable 32-bit applications to True.
The production server doesn't like the 32 bit and is acting up. The dlls can't be used. 
I must find the equivalent 64 bit. Can someone point me to where I can find them?

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to install the `Team Explorer` on production machine. Just the TFS Assemblies is not enough. It needs to have the entire TFS Object model available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sudhir3, thank you for your suggestion. 
Like I said, the code is not an issue and it works, but that involved setting the 32 bit flag on the app pool.
Further investigations lead me to know that there is no equivalent of 64 bit for the 32 bit dll. VS itself is still 32 bit. No near conversion by microsoft to 64 bit is near.

So, I I ended up leaving the IIS 32 bit flag in the app pool set to false and created web api webservice that passed values to a powershell cmdlet, which in turn executes my TFS api code.